# Printed pages are displaced upwards

Tags: xubuntu, printing, hp

The system is **Xubuntu 20.04.3**.
The Printer/Scanner is **HP All In One 3790**.
The software is **HPLIP 3.20.6** and it has been downloaded and installed manually from the HP site.

The problem is that all the pages that are printed, either text or images, are all displaced upwards so that if the document is text for example, the first line is always printed outside the paper top boundary and therefore not printed at all.

I have created the sample below, just to show you what I mean. The light grey rectangle represents the paper and the dark grey one represents the document and how it's printed.

[image]

This problem appears when I'm printing from **Xubuntu** only. All documents that are printed from the phone for example, using **HP Smart**, are printed perfectly in place. I 've also tested printing from Manjaro Linux using software that has not been manually downloaded from HP and all printed documents are displaced similarly.

I have tried removing all top and bottom boundaries but nothing changed. The only configuration that seems to work is to lower the upper boundary so that the top limit resembles the bottom one, which prints pages with much less content since both top and bottom empty spaces are too big.

Any ideas on how to fix this please?

Comment: what app are you printing from? please [edit] into your question as this may be significant.

Comment: All apps produce the same result. Chrome, Kate, PDF reader (Atril), Gimp.

Comment: have you checked how the the printer settings in `Settings > Printer` are configured and in CUPS https://linuxhint.com/cups_print_server_ubuntu/

Comment: A wise user would jettison HPLIP and use this modern printer with a well-tested and reliable printing system designed for Ubuntu 20.04 onwards. See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting